# 'a4j:commandButton' oncomplete processing nullifies backing bean's variables (seam2.3.0.final/jsf2/rf4)

Tags: seam

I have an entry form with Seam-generated Entity and EntityHome type backing beans. Since the user wants a confirmation pop up dialog before saving the entered data, I've replaced the auto-generated 'h:commandButton' with a 'a4j:commandButton' and attached a modal panel to its 'oncomplete' event:

the Edit.xhtml entry form bit:

```
. . . . . 

<div class="actionButtons">

        <a:commandButton id="save"
                      value="Save"
                 oncomplete="#{rich:component('confirmCreatePanel')}.show();"
                   disabled="#{!userProjectRolesHome.wired}"
                   rendered="#{!userProjectRolesHome.managed}">
            <s:conversationId/>
        </a:commandButton>

    </div>

    <rich:popupPanel modal="true" id="confirmCreatePanel" moveable="false" resizeable="false" height="120">
      <f:facet name="header">Confirm</f:facet> 
      <div class="actionButtons">
        <rich:panel style="align:center;">
          <h:outputText value="Are you sure you want to create this ?" />
          <table width="100%">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" width="50%">
                  <a:commandButton type="submit" value="Yes" action="#{userProjectRolesHome.persist}"
                    oncomplete="#{rich:component('confirmCreatePanel')}.hide()"/>
                </td>
                <td align="center" width="50%">
                  <a:commandButton type="submit" value="No" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmCreatePanel')}.hide()"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </rich:panel>
      </div> 
    </rich:popupPanel>
```

When clicked on the 'Save' button the 'confirmCreatePanel' pops up OK, but then when the user clicks on the mod.panel 'Yes' and the 'persist()' is called I get an Exception complaining about the member variables being 'null'.

If I call 'persist()' from the 'action' attribute of the either the 'a4j:commandButton' or 'h:commandButton' everything works OK. the 'oncomplete' processing messes the things up and it used to work.

This same code works with Seam 2.2.0.Final/RF3.3.3/JSF1.2. it's not working now after an upgrade to Seam2.3.0.Final/RF4/JSF2 what's changed here ?

```
2013-02-06 12:57:50,394 ERROR [clahrc.session.UserProjectRolesHome]     user-project-role persisting or emailing failed: 
 javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes     [clahrc.entity.UserProjectRoles] during persist time for groups    [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null',     propertyPath=projects, rootBeanClass=class clahrc.entity.UserProjectRoles,     messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=users,     rootBeanClass=class clahrc.entity.UserProjectRoles,     messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=roles,  rootBeanClass=class clahrc.entity.UserProjectRoles, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1081)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:973)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(EntityManagerInvocationHandler.java:46)
    at $Proxy77.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.seam.framework.EntityHome.persist(EntityHome.java:85)
    at clahrc.session.UserProjectRolesHome.persist(UserProjectRolesHome.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor$1.work(TransactionInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Work.workInTransaction(Work.java:61)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:186)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:104)
    at clahrc.session.UserProjectRolesHome_$$_javassist_seam_21.persist(UserProjectRolesHome_$$_javassist_seam_21.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:348)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding 's:conversationId' to the model panel's 'Yes' 'a:commandButton' seems to have fixed it for now.